# Rewriting a second order ODE as a first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have the ODE

$\left(\frac{y'}{x^2 \rho(x)} \right)' + \frac{4 \pi G \rho(x)}{x^2 P(x)}\, y - \left( \frac{F(x)}{x^2 \rho(x)} \right)' = 0$

with the boundary conditions $y(x=0)=0, y(x=1)=0$. The independent variable is $x$, the variable I would like to solve for is $y(x)$, the functions $\rho$, $P$, and $F$ are all known as well as the constants $G$ and $4\pi$ (duh).

I would like to solve this equation numerically using scipy's `sp.integrate.bvp_solve`. For this I need to turn it into a first order system.

This is my attempt:

\begin{align}
    y_1' &= y_2 \\
    y_2' &= \left(\frac{F}{x^2 \rho} \right)' - \frac{4 \pi G \rho}{x^2 P}\, y
\end{align}

but I think that it is not correct because the first term in the original equation does not seem properly represented. Can someone please help?

Comment: The LHside of your second ODE should be $\left( \frac{y_2}{x^2 \rho(x)}\right)^\prime$ instead of $y_2^\prime$; and of course you should have $y_1$ instead of $y$ in the RHside.

Comment: @Pacciu thanks - that makes a lot more sense - however I am still stuck as at least the examples in scipy all have "pure" variables on the LHS. Can I maybe integrate the second ODE to get something "pure"? Or do you have advice on how to proceed from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original ODE can be written also as

$\left(\frac{y'-F(x)}{x^2 \rho(x)} \right)' + \frac{4 \pi G \rho(x)}{x^2 P(x)}\, y  = 0$

and making

$$
\cases{y_1 = y\\
y_2=\frac{y_1'-F(x)}{x^2 \rho(x)} 
}
$$

can be represented as

$$
\cases{
y'_1 = x^2\rho(x) y_2+F(x)\\
y'_2 = -\frac{4\pi G \rho(x)}{x^2 P(x)}y_1
}.
$$

Comment: It works, it works, oh my gosh it works! You have made me a very happy person today. Thank you!